# Android debugger doesn't connect

Tags: java, android, debugging, button

I use eclipse for debug android application.
When I will press run, it run application. But press on some button invokes exception.
So I try to debug but seems that debugger stops on:

```
 Attemting to connecto debugger to 'com.example.myapplication' on port 8867.
```

It doesn't respond.

What it can be? How to resolve? Any tips please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try if it works.

- Uninstall your previous APK and then install it again and try to RUN it.

And are you getting this in your log?

```
Attemting to connecto debugger to 'com.example.myapplication' on port 8867.

Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.
```

Then try below steps, it might work

- Close Eclipse.
- Remove USB.
- Go to task manager, and delete all 'eclipse.exe' (in my case I had 4-5 instances).
- Also delete 'adb.exe'.
- Restart Eclipse.
- Reconnect USB.

Answer (score 1):

Some application require permission for debugging process. Check for `android.permission.SET_DEBUG_AP`P permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<manifest>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

You can also add `android:debuggable="true"` in the application tag of AndroidManifest.xml.